# iOS Animated Bezier Path

Tags: ios, core-animation, cashapelayer

I am looking to do a looping Fade In/Out Animation with bezier paths in iOS for about 6 curves. I have looked in to the documentation on CAShapeLayers and using UIBezierPaths but I am not finding any solid documentation on animating and changing properties of more than one path over and over.

I have created my paths like so:

```
UIBezierPath *rightInner = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(120, 30) radius:15 startAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(315) endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(45) clockwise:YES];
UIBezierPath *rightMiddle = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(120, 30) radius:35 startAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(315) endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(45) clockwise:YES];
UIBezierPath *rightOuter = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(120, 30) radius:55 startAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(315) endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(45) clockwise:YES];
```

What is the best way to animate these fading in and out over and over and possibly changing their colors? Should I be using CAShapeLayers in some way? I would really like to avoid using an image sequence as memory issues and performance are huge factors here.

Thanks!

Comment: Only the color (or opacity) changes and the time between fading in and out is the same for each repeat?

Comment: Maybe you can use one CAShapeLayer per path, add each one of these layers as sublayers of one CALayer, and animate their strokeStart/End/Color property ?

Comment: You need to be more specific about the animation(s) that you want. Do you want all the paths to fade in and out together? Do you want an entire path to fade in and out as a unit, or do you want to animate drawing it onto the screen start to finish? Do you want them to fade in and out independently of each other? Do you want the color changes to animate? Do you want the color change animations to happen at the same time as the fade in/out animations?